# Is it possible to use regular expressions to find a string that could have a stray space any place in it?

Tags: regex

I haven't seen an answer to this specific question anywhere.  My apologies if someone identifies it as a dupe.  What I am wondering is: is it possible to search for:

```
abcdefghijk
```

matching any of the following:

```
a bcdefghijk
ab cdefghijk
abc defghijk
abcd efghijk
abcde fghijk
abcdef ghijk
abcdefg hijk
abcdefgh ijk
abcdefghi jk
abcdefghij k
```

I.e. I know the string I want to find, but it can end up with a stray space at any place.

Seems like this may be out of scope with regex, but wanted to be sure.

Comment: You could test for `a ?b ?c ?d ?e ?f ?g ?h ?i ?j ?k`, then inspect whether the total length of the resulting match is either `len(original_string)` or +1

Comment: well, if this is the best possible answer: /cats/ -> /c\s*a\s*t\s*s/
then it's a dupe.  was hoping something better would be possible, but it does look like that question got a lot of views so I guess that is the best possible?

Comment: The dupe will make it match strings with more than one space in them though. I got the impression you only want to allow max 1 space?

Comment: Happy to close as a dupe if anyone else wants to vote to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to use a positive lookahead to find a space combined with a negative lookahead to *not* find a space.

Then let every character be followed by an optional space.

```
^(?=.* (?!.* ))?a ?b ?c ?d ?e ?f ?g ?h ?i ?j ?k ?$
```

- `(?=` - positive lookahead start

  - `.*`  - anything followed by space
  - `(?!` - negative lookahead start

    - `.*`  - anything followed by a space
  - `)` - negative lookahead end
- `)` - positive lookahead end
- `?` - 0 or 1 match

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0n2M9n/1)

Comment: Thanks, I like this better than the answer in the possible dupe.  Hopefully I don't get too many downvotes to keep your awesome answer here.

Comment: @chrismead Yeah :-) Perhaps there are more elegant solutions to this, but this was the first thing that popped up in my mind. It _feels_ like it should be possible to simplify it though.